# How to make all items the same width but as small as possible?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Using flex or some alternative, how can I achieve the following?

- Each item should be displayed side-by-side
- The width of each item should be as small as possible, but large enough so that **each item is of equal width**
- If all the items cannot fit on one row, the items should wrap appropriately

This is what I've tried so far: https://jsfiddle.net/nqyds03m/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: max-content;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 0.25rem;
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    An item with a lot of text indeed!
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Short item
  </div>
</div>
```

The result is close enough, but not perfect. The items should be larger in the above example so that the text on the first item fits on one line, and the second item should grow to match the first.

I would like to avoid JavaScript if possible, but if a little JavaScript is necessary that is OK, as long as it remains performant like pure CSS.

Comment: well, what's wrong? how about a working snippet to showcase the problem.  Help your helpers!

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Pytth I have updated question

Comment: If you want wrapping I doubt you can use `max-content`.

Comment: I do not believe this is possible without Javascript

Comment: always 2 items?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Not always 2 items

Answer (score 4):

Without wrapping we can easily do this with CSS grid:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  grid-auto-columns:1fr;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    An item with a lot of text indeed!
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Short item
  </div>
</div>
```

To have wrapping, I think you will need some JS. Here is an idea where I will get the width of items then set a variable with that width.

```js
document.querySelector('.container').style.setProperty("--w",document.querySelector('.item').offsetWidth+"px") 
document.querySelector('.container').style.display="grid";
```

```css
.container {
  /* I need the below to have the same width for all the items
     then I will override it after getting that width */
  display: inline-block; 
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,var(--w));
  grid-gap:0.5rem;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    An item with a lot of text indeed!
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Short item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    another item
  </div>
</div>
```

Same idea using flexbox:

```js
document.querySelector('.container').style.setProperty("--w",document.querySelector('.item').offsetWidth+"px") 
document.querySelector('.container').style.display="flex";
```

```css
.container {
  /* I need the below to have the same width for all the items
     then I will override it after getting that width */
  display: inline-block;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.item {
  width:var(--w);
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin:0.25rem
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    An item with a lot of text indeed!
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Short item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    another item
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I update the second solution so that the elements size will update dynamically if its content changes? and would this cause jitter when it's updating?

Comment: @DavidCallanan it will depend on how your content will change, based on that we can update the code

Comment: It could change in any way (I am currently using the Svelte framework to handle changes). I think the MutationObserver API might work

Comment: @DavidCallanan so simply re-run my JS code that you can put inside a function but make sure to enable the display:inline-block initially to be abe to get the width then you put it back to display:flex

Comment: Ok thanks, will this result in a temporary flicker when changing to inline-block?

Comment: @DavidCallanan I cannot confirm, you may have to test and see what happen in your particular case

Answer (score -1):

Use the `column` for vertical alignment with the inline-flex.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.item {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    An item with a lot of text indeed!
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Short item
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A column is not what the OP wants. The items are supposed to be in a row AND equal width